# Angular - about $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled()

Tags: angularjs, debugging

Can someone explain me how to see impact of turn off debugInfoEnabled ?

I see nothing, no change in console, app isn't faster.

Comment: you could get some info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002113/how-compileprovider-debuginfoenabled-set-to-false-improve-performance-in-angula

Comment: One of the good read on [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/12/22/exploring-angular-1.3-disabling-debug-info.html) and super [official](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) docs can lets you clearly understand what does that do exactly.

Comment: I have made one [demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/NnipcKch5pCA2eH9rYPc/) for you. You can see that after adding the config the associated in-built directives are not getting added in DOM

Comment: Thanks for links, I don't see real diff in profiling when I turn on/off

Comment: True, recently I tried this on a large enterprise app. did spot much difference in performance thru CPU profiling or timeline....